# A conjecture on diophantine equation

Tags: diophantine-equations, conjectures, abc-conjecture

Let $A, B, C$ be given three [integer numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer), $A^2+B^2+C^2 \ne 0$;  and $f(x,y,z)=0$ be given [diophantine equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation).

Then exist $N_0 > 2$ such that $m, n, k \ge N_0$ the equation as follows:

$f(x,y,z)+Ax^n+By^m+Cz^k=0$ with condition $gcd(x,y)=gcd(y,z)=gcd(z,x)=1$ has only finitely solutions

**Question:** The conjecture above is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $f(x,y,z) = x - y$, $A = 1$, $B = -1$, $C = 0$, $m = n$.

Comment: I want mean $gcd(x,y,z)=1$, because the Fermat equation $x^n+y^n=z^n$ alway has $x=z, y=0$

Comment: OK, take $x=y$, $z = 1$ in my example.

Comment: OK, You are right. $gcd(x,x,1)=1$, your example $x-x+x^n-x^n+0.1=0$ but this equation don't has $z$. So I think should adding stronger condition $gcd(x,y)=gcd(y,z)=gcd(z,x)=1$  Dear @RobertIsael ? Final condition in the topic. I will don't changes